# drupal 6 : include() once additional functions and classes that will be available on entire site

Tags: drupal, file, include, hook

i got some php classes and functions that i want to make it avliable in the whole site, where i should put the include() ?
i tried hook_init() but its then includes it on every section (page, note ) over and over again even if i do include once...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The best way to add your own PHP functions to Drupal, would be to create your own function library module.](http://www.bobbymods.com/faq/drupal-modules/how-do-i-add-my-own-php-functions-drupal)

Answer (score 0):

Drupal automatically imports any functions that are in the my_module.module file. This is the simpest way to include functions and classes in a Drupal site. Since these are included in every full bootstrap of Drupal ideally you would limit the number of functions in a module file. However if you want them to be always included this is the easiest way.

If you need more fine grained control over when code is included you can use the function [module_load_include()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_load_include/6). This function is used frequently to load the code for admin pages and other functions that have a limited scope.

There are few cases where you'd want to load a library file on every page load, in those cases you can use the above function in the mymodule_init() hook and the file should only be loaded once, since the function uses require_once(), instead of include().